# The basis of naming reaching laws for sliding surface in Sliding Mode Control

Tags: controller, controls, nonlinear-functions, nonlinear-equation, non-linear

The following article explains the basis for naming the "reaching law" in "sliding Mode Control (SMC)". This article will help those who need to name the "reaching law" in "Sliding Mode Control".
[https://www.researchgate.net/publication/377205280_The_basis_of_naming_reaching_laws_for_sliding_surface_in_Sliding_Mode_Control_approaches](https://stackoverflow.com)

One of the problems with finding the right name for "law of reaching" in Sliding Mode Control (SMC) is that researchers don't put the right names for "reaching law". A standard was mentioned in this article.